# React: How to get a elements hight, that disappears and appears with new size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, use-ref

Sorry for the confusing title

I'm adding editing feature to a forum, and I need to get the topic's title elements height and width, so that I click the EDIT button, component re-renders and instead of the title we have a text input that has title's width and height. The problem is that I can properly do this just once. If I edit for the second time with no refresh and I save, the next text input has the first edited titles width/height

Here my code:

```
export default TopicComponent(someProps...){

const titleRef = useRef('');
const [isAuthor, setIsAuthor] = useState(author === user.id);
  const [editContentState, setEditContent] = useState(false);
  const [titleSize, setTitleSize] = useState({ height: null, width: null });

 useEffect(() => {
   setTitleSize({height: titleRef.current ? titleRef.current.offsetHeight : null, width: titleRef.current ? titleRef.current.offsetWidth : null})
  },[]);
function edit() {
    
    setIsAuthor(!isAuthor);
    setEditContent(!editContentState);
  }

  async function discard() {
   
    setIsAuthor(!isAuthor);
    setEditContent(!editContentState);
  }

 async function handleUpdateTopic() {
    setIsAuthor(!isAuthor);
    setEditContent(!editContentState);

   //do more stuff
  }

return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <span>
        <img alt="User Profile Pic" src={img_url} />
        <div className={styles.info}>
          {editContentState ? (
            <input
              className={styles.comment_box}
              style={{ height: titleSize.height, width: titleSize.width }}
              defaultValue={topicContent.title}
              onChange={(e) => (topicContent.title = e.target.value)}
            />
          ) : (
            <h1 ref={titleRef}>{topicContent.title}</h1>
          )}
          <p>
            {name} {surname}
          </p>
          {editContentState && (
            <>
              <button
                style={{ width: 200 }}
                type="button"
                onClick={handleUpdateTopic}
              >
                Save Changes
              </button>
              <button type="button" onClick={discard}>
                Discard changes
              </button>
            </>
          )}
          {isAuthor && (
            <button type="button" onClick={edit}>
              Edit
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </span>
```

So I know that this way with useEffect I'm setting titleSize state just once, I tried to just mutate titleSize properies straight as:

```
useEffec(()=> {
titleSize.width = titleRef.current ? titleRef.current.offsetWidth : null })
```

Without forcing a re-rendering, but I'm getting the same result, I can just get first load's title element height & width.

Anyone knows a better approach to to this? I reached the net but unafortunately I didnt get expected answers (probably cause I didnt use correct keywords to reach the correct answer)

Any help truly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like your ```useEffect``` does not have anything in the dependency array, so it is executed only when the component is mounted. I would change it to include the ```titleRef``` in that array, so it can be run every time the ```titleRef``` changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass topicContent to useEffect. so when the topicContent change, the useEffect runs again.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTitleSize({height: titleRef.current ? titleRef.current.offsetHeight : null, width: titleRef.current ? titleRef.current.offsetWidth : null})
},[topicContent]);
```